# Should people with high reputation fix minor grammar issues?

Tags: discussion, grammatical-correction

I was looking at [java, bit operation, how to calculate the length back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25304272/java-bit-operation-how-to-calculate-the-length-back) which contains the following sentence:

> In a java programe, people store data in a byte array, and the first two byte were used to store the length of data,

which has a misspelling of programme/program, mismatched word-tenses between "store" and "were", and a missing "s" in "bytes".

These are all truly minor problems that don't detract from the understandability of the question.  IIUC these edits are considered too minor for people with reputation less than 2000 because it clobbers the review queue.

I realize those aren't the only problems with the question, but I'm asking more generally if people with reputation higher than 2000 should go ahead and fix these types of minor grammatical issues or leave them be?

Comment: Yes, please fix them.

Comment: In England, 'programme' is how they spell 'programme'. They have a number of other spelling differences from American English (as do we in Canada and, I'm sure, other Commonwealth countries). (For example 'analogue' vs 'analog' or 'dialogue' vs 'dialog'.)

Comment: @RobH In the UK, "programme" is the spelling for the folded card you get when you go to a theatre, which tells you when the intermission will be; we spell "program" in the computing sense without the extra "-me", for at least a few decades. Likewise, it's "analogue" when it's analogous to something and "dialogue" when you engage in conversation with somebody, but for the technical terms I only see "analog" and "dialog".

Comment: I (4k reputation) have no problem to edit posts from authors with a 20k+ reputation. In fact I see numerous hi-reputation authors doing rather sloppy posts, with trends like putting each sentence into a new line, or not using dots to end sentences.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I do not see any harm caused by such an edit. It improves the readability of the question, as it is easier to read correctly spelled and formulated texts, because they meet the expectation our brain is building while reading them (this is especially true if english is not the readers native language).

So the edit improves something without bothering anyone else - we should be happy about it.

Comment: I don't know, it felt kind of nitpicky and I'm not sure everyone always enjoys being corrected at that level..  Maybe I'm just being over sensitive?

Comment: @thebjorn IMO one should always be happy to be corrected as long as it is an improvement, especially on a site like SO, which is focussed on building a collection of high quality content together. So I would not say you are over sensitive (it is a human feeling and perfectly fine), but you should try to look at it from the community angle, to appreciate the fact that content that you have created was further improved to benefit other people.

Comment: worse case scenario, even if you have over 2K, the OP can still rollback, no?  if he doesn't like it, it's likely what he'll do

Comment: Why doesn't it fall under the "too minor" reject reason? For example I'm stuck at a question where the single edit was "somtimes" to "sometimes". Should I really have allowed that?

Comment: @EduardLuca Too minor is used when other glaring problems are left. If a post really only needs a single word changed then its an ok edit iirc. I'd still recommand people with over 2k to do it though as to not clutter the que.